# Remover primeira palavra da String

Tags: java, string

Tenho um `stringBuffer` com uma frase dentro. Preciso retirar a primeira palavra da string. Fazendo com que a segunda se torne primeira e a quantidade de palavras seja x-1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
str.replace(0, str.indexOf(" ") + 1, ""); // = "ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
```

Answer (score 6):

Utilize [`indexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) e [`delete(int start, int end)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete%28int,%20int%29)

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Palavra1 Palavra2");
int index = sb.indexOf(" ");
sb.delete(0, index + 1);//+1 para remover também o espaço
```

Answer (score 2):

Para remover uma palavra de uma frase, pode-se fazer:

```
public static void replaceAll(StringBuffer builder, String from, String to)
   {
      int index = builder.indexOf(from);
      while (index != -1)
      {
         builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
         index += to.length();
         index = builder.indexOf(from, index);
      }

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Foo Bar Baz Poo");
replaceAll(sb, "Bar", "Laa"); // Vai substituir a palavra "Bar" por "Laa"
System.out.println(sb); // Foo Laa Baz Poo
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/dczFDI)</kbd>

---

Se quiser remover o primeiro caractere de uma *string*, poderá ser usado o método [`deleteCharAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#deleteCharAt(int)) que vai remover o caractere na posição especificada.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Palavra");
sb.deleteCharAt(0);
System.out.println(sb); // alavra
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/dczFDI)</kbd>

Para remover o último caractere de uma *string*, pode-se fazer:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Palavra");
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1); 
// Ou sb.setLength(sb.length() -1);
System.out.println(sb); // Palavr
```

Comment: mas eu nao sei o tamanho da palavra, pois pode variar. O que seria necessário é algo como um `split`, mas creio que não funcione com `stringBuffer`.

Comment: Mas eu preciso retirar a palavra inteira e não só o primeiro caractere.